# Speed-up nested cross-validation

Tags: scikit-learn, parallel-processing

In order to speed-up nested cross-validation with sklearn, is it better to fix n_jobs=-1 in inner or outer loop, since nested parallelism is not allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an an open question, see e.g. this open [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10232) on scikit-learn's github page.

Another approach is to use a Message Passing Interface (MPI) to exploit multiple processors, see e.g. this [blogpost](https://k-d-w.org/blog/95/mpi-based-nested-cross-validation-for-scikit-learn) using [MPI4PY](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).