# How to speed up nested cross validation in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, dask, cross-validation

From what I've found there is 1 other question like this ([Speed-up nested cross-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629112/speed-up-nested-cross-validation)) however installing MPI does not work for me after trying several fixes also suggested on this site and microsoft, so I am hoping there is another package or answer to this question.

I am looking to compare multiple algorithms and gridsearch a wide range of parameters (maybe too many parameters?), what ways are there besides mpi4py which could speed up running my code? As I understand it I cannot use n_jobs=-1 as that is then not nested?

Also to note, I have not been able to run this on the many parameters I am trying to look at below (runs longer than I have time). Only have results after 2 hours if I give each model only 2 parameters to compare. Also I run this code on a dataset of 252 rows and 25 feature columns with 4 categorical variables to predict ('certain', 'likely', 'possible', or 'unknown') whether a gene (with 252 genes) affects a disease. Using SMOTE increases the sample size to 420 which is then what goes into use.

```
dataset= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = dataset.drop(["gene"],1)
df = data.iloc[:,0:24]
df = df.fillna(0)
X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_value = le.fit_transform(["certain", "likely", "possible", "unlikely"])
Y = le.fit_transform(data["category"])

sm = SMOTE(random_state=100)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)

seed = 7
logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear',multi_class='auto')
LR_par= {'penalty':['l1'], 'C': [0.5, 1, 5, 10], 'max_iter':[500, 1000, 5000]}

rfc =RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {'bootstrap': [True, False],
              'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
              'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4,25],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 25],
              'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]}

mlp = MLPClassifier(random_state=seed)
parameter_space = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,20), (10,20,10), (50,)],
     'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
     'solver': ['adam', 'sgd'],
     'max_iter': [10000],
     'alpha': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001],
     'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}

gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(min_samples_split=25, min_samples_leaf=25)
param = {"loss":["deviance"],
    "learning_rate": [0.15,0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001],
    "min_samples_split": [2, 5, 10, 25],
    "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 4,25],
    "max_depth":[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
    "max_features":['auto', 'sqrt'],
    "criterion": ["friedman_mse"],
    "n_estimators":[200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]
    }

svm = SVC(gamma="scale", probability=True)
tuned_parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':(1,0.25,0.5,0.75)}

def baseline_model(optimizer='adam', learn_rate=0.01):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X_res.shape[1], activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu')) #8 is the dim/ the number of hidden units (units are the kernel)
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

keras = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, batch_size=32, epochs=100, verbose=0)
learn_rate = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
kerasparams = dict(optimizer=optimizer, learn_rate=learn_rate)

inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

models = []
models.append(('GBM', GridSearchCV(gbm, param, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('RFC', GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('LR', GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('SVM', GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('MLP', GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('Keras', GridSearchCV(estimator=keras, param_grid=kerasparams, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))


results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


for name, model in models:
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
    print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_))
```

As an example, most of the dataset is binary and looks like this:

```
gene   Tissue    Druggable Eigenvalue CADDvalue Catalogpresence   Category
ACE      1           1         1          0           1            Certain
ABO      1           0         0          0           0            Likely
TP53     1           1         0          0           0            Possible
```

Any guidance on how I could speed this up would be appreciated.

Edit: I have also tried using parallel processing with dask, but I am not sure I am doing it right, and it doesn't seem to run any faster:

```
for name, model in models:
    with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
        nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(nested_cv_results)
        names.append(name)
        msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
        print(msg)
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    #print("Best Estimator: \n{}\n".format(model.best_estimator_))
        print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
        print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_)) #average of all cv folds for a single combination of the parameters you specify
```

Edit: also to note with reducing the gridsearch, I have tried with for example 5 parameters per model however this still takes several hours to complete, so whilst trimming down the number will be helpful, if there is any advice for efficency beyond that I would be grateful.

Comment: There are several ways to get your code running faster: 1) In all `GridSearch`   functions set `n_jobs=2` or `n_jobs=3` or even `n_jobs=-1` (depends on the number of CPU kernels available);  2) Use RandomizedSearchCV instead (it could help you to get optimal solution faster); 3) reduce the number of grid points passed to GridSearch; 4) combine all of these approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your repsonse, unfortunately I can't have anything other than n_jobs=1 for nested CV (according to scikit-learn's site: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html) however RandomizedSearchCV sounds like it might be more ideal for me so I will look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Instead of `GridSearch` try using [`HyperOpt`](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) - it's a Python library for serial and parallel optimization.
2. I would reduce the dimensionality by using [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) or [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html). Probably UMAP is the better choice.

After you apply `SMOTE`:

```
import umap

dim_reduced = umap.UMAP(
        min_dist=min_dist,
        n_neighbors=neighbours,
        random_state=1234,
    ).fit_transform(smote_output)
```

And then you can use `dim_reduced` for the train test split.

Reducing the dimensionality will help to remove noise from the data and instead of dealing with 25 features you'll bring them down to 2 (using UMAP) or the number of components you choose (using PCA). Which should have significant implications on the performance.

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I am having a go a what you suggested and it seems to be going well so far (although stuck on hyperopt not recognising n_jobs=1 but I will keep trying), for the reduction of dimensionality (which I do not know much about) do I need to worry about a loss of information? When I look at how my features correlate and how my models use the features without the gridsearch there are only 3-4 features not weighted with importance or correlating, so I am concerned UMAP or PCA would reduce more than those 3-4.

Comment: `"arguably preserves more of the global structure with superior run time performance"` taken from https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426. If it reduces more than those 3-4 features, which isn't necessarily a bad thing, it means there was a lot of noisy features in your data. If they are important / not noise UMAP will pick them up for sure. Check this comment as well https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/122#issuecomment-412530409

Answer (score 3):

The [Dask-ML](https://ml.dask.org) has scalable implementations  `GridSearchCV` and `RandomSearchCV` that are, I believe, drop in replacements for Scikit-Learn.  They were developed alongside Scikit-Learn developers.

- https://ml.dask.org/hyper-parameter-search.html

They can be faster for two reasons:

- They avoid repeating shared work between different stages of a Pipeline
- They can scale out to a cluster anywhere you can deploy Dask ([which is easy on most cluster infrastructure](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html))

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy win in your situation and that is .... start using parallel processing :). `dask` will help you if you have a cluster (it will work on a single machine, but the improvement compared to the default scheduling in `sklearn` is not significant), but if you plan to run it on a single machine (but have several cores/threads and "enough" memory) then you can run nested CV in parallel. The only trick is that `sklearn` will not allow you to run the **outer CV** loop in multiple processes. However, **it will allow you to run the inner loop in multiple threads**.

At the moment you have `n_jobs=None` in the outer CV loop (that's the default in `cross_val_score`), which means `n_jobs=1` and that's the only option that you can use with `sklearn` in the nested CV.

However, you can achieve and easy gain by setting `n_jobs=some_reasonable_number` in all `GridSearchCV` that you use. `some_reasonable_number` does not have to be `-1` (but it is a good starting point). Some algorithms either plateau on `n_jobs=n_cores` instead of `n_threads` (for example, `xgboost`) or already have built-in multi-processing (like `RandomForestClassifier`, for example) and there might be clashes if you spawn too many processes.

Comment: Why is n_jobs=1 the only option in nested CV?

Comment: unfortunately, I do not know the answer to the question "why" as I didn't write the code.
But I imagine the logic *could be* that the user still has parallelization capability on the inside layer, and on a single machine (where one can run sklearn) there is typically not enough resources to spawn more than 4-8 threads efficiently in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are trying to parallelize [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#nested-versus-non-nested-cross-validation) from the `sklearn` docs. If this is the case, then here is one possible approach to address

> why dask is not working

and

> Any kind of constructive guidance or further knowledge on this problem

General imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, KFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import dask_ml.model_selection as dcv


import time
```

Data

- I defined 3 datasets to try out implementation of `dask_ml`

  - the size, # rows, of the third (Dataset 3) one is adjustable and can be arbirarily increased depending on your computing power

    - I timed execution of `dask_ml` using this dataset only
  - the code below works for all 3 datasets
  - Dataset 1 is a slightly longer version of sample data in SO question

```
#### Dataset 1 - longer version of data in the question
d = """gene Tissue Druggable Eigenvalue CADDvalue Catalogpresence Category
ACE 1 1 1 0 1 Certain
ABO 1 0 0 0 0 Likely
TP53 1 1 0 0 0 Possible"""
data = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in d.split('\n')])
data.columns = data.loc[0,:]
data.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
data = pd.concat([data]*15)

data = data.drop(["gene"],1)
df = data.iloc[:,0:5]

X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_value = le.fit_transform(["Certain", "Likely", "Possible"])
Y = le.fit_transform(data["Category"])

sm = SMOTE(random_state=100)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)
```

```
#### Dataset 2 - iris dataset from example in sklearn nested cross validation docs
# Load the dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X_res = iris.data
y_res = iris.target
```

```
#### Dataset 3 - size (#rows, #columns) is adjustable (I used this to time code execution)
X_res = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(300,50), columns=['col_'+str(c+1) for c in list(range(50))])
from random import shuffle
cats = ["paris", "barcelona", "kolkata", "new york", 'sydney']
y_values = cats*int(len(X_res)/len(cats))
shuffle(y_values)
y_res = pd.Series(y_values)
```

Instantiate classifiers - no changes from code in the question

```
seed = 7
logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear',multi_class='auto')
LR_par= {'penalty':['l1'], 'C': [0.5, 1, 5, 10], 'max_iter':[500, 1000, 5000]}

mlp = MLPClassifier(random_state=seed)
parameter_space = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,20), (10,20,10), (50,)],
     'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
     'solver': ['adam', 'sgd'],
     'max_iter': [10000],
     'alpha': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001],
     'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}

rfc =RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {'bootstrap': [True, False],
              'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
              'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4,25],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 25],
              'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]}

gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(min_samples_split=25, min_samples_leaf=25)
param = {"loss":["deviance"],
    "learning_rate": [0.15,0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001],
    "min_samples_split": [2, 5, 10, 25],
    "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 4,25],
    "max_depth":[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
    "max_features":['auto', 'sqrt'],
    "criterion": ["friedman_mse"],
    "n_estimators":[200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]
    }

svm = SVC(gamma="scale", probability=True)
tuned_parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':(1,0.25,0.5,0.75)}
```

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
```

Use `GridSearchCV` as implemented by `dask_ml` (as originally suggested by @MRocklin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881669/4057186)) - see the `dask_ml` docs for [`dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV`](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#dask-ml-model-selection-gridsearchcv)

- for brevity I am excluding `KerasClassifier` and the helper function `baseline_model()` but my approach to handling the former would be the same as for the others

```
models = []
models.append(('MLP', dcv.GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('GBM', dcv.GridSearchCV(gbm, param, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('RFC', dcv.GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('LR', dcv.GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('SVM', dcv.GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
```

Initialize an extra blank list to hold non-nested CV results

```
non_nested_results = []
nested_results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Joblib and `dask` client setup

- I created the cluster on my local machine

  - see [single machine `dask.distributed`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html#single-machine-dask-distributed)

```
# Create a local cluster
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(processes=False, threads_per_worker=4,
        n_workers=1, memory_limit='6GB')
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

Perform Nested CV per the [`sklearn` docs example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#nested-versus-non-nested-cross-validation)

- first perform `GridSearchCV`
- second use `cross_val_score`
- note that, for demonstration purposes, I have only used 1 `sklearn` model (`SVC`) from the list of models in the example code in the question

```
start = time.time()
for name, model in [models[-1]]:
  # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
  with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  non_nested_results.append(model.best_score_)

  # Nested CV with parameter optimization
  nested_score = cross_val_score(model, X=X_train, y=Y_train, cv=outer_cv)
  nested_results.append(nested_score.mean())

  names.append(name)
  msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" %\
        (name, np.mean(nested_results)*100, np.std(nested_results)*100)
  print(msg)
  print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
  print("Best Estimator: \n{}\n".format(model.best_estimator_))
  print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
  print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_))

score_difference = [a_i - b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(non_nested_results, nested_results)]
print("Average difference of {0:6f} with std. dev. of {1:6f}."
      .format(np.mean(score_difference), np.std(score_difference)))

print('Total running time of the script: {:.2f} seconds' .format(time.time()-start))

client.close()
```

Below are the outputs (with script execution timing) using dataset 3

Output+Timing without `dask`<sup>1</sup>

```
Nested CV Accuracy SVM: 20.416667 (+/- 0.000000 )
Test set accuracy: 16.67 %
Best Estimator: 
SVC(C=0.75, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Best Parameters: 
{'C': 0.75, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Best CV Score: 
0.2375

Average difference of 0.033333 with std. dev. of 0.000000.
Total running time of the script: 23.96 seconds
```

Output+Timing with `dask` (using `n_workers=1` and `threads_per_worker=4`)<sup>2</sup>

```
Nested CV Accuracy SVM: 18.750000 (+/- 0.000000 )
Test set accuracy: 13.33 %
Best Estimator: 
SVC(C=0.5, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Best Parameters: 
{'C': 0.5, 'kernel': 'rbf'}

Best CV Score: 
0.1916666666666667

Average difference of 0.004167 with std. dev. of 0.000000.
Total running time of the script: 8.84 seconds
```

Output+Timing with `dask` (using `n_workers=4` and `threads_per_worker=4`)<sup>2</sup>

```
Nested CV Accuracy SVM: 23.333333 (+/- 0.000000 )
Test set accuracy: 21.67 %
Best Estimator: 
SVC(C=0.25, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Best Parameters: 
{'C': 0.25, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Best CV Score: 
0.25

Average difference of 0.016667 with std. dev. of 0.000000.
Total running time of the script: 7.52 seconds
```

Output+Timing with `dask` (using `n_workers=1` and `threads_per_worker=8`)<sup>2</sup>

```
Nested CV Accuracy SVM: 20.416667 (+/- 0.000000 )
Test set accuracy: 18.33 %
Best Estimator: 
SVC(C=1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Best Parameters: 
{'C': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}

Best CV Score: 
0.23333333333333334

Average difference of 0.029167 with std. dev. of 0.000000.
Total running time of the script: 7.06 seconds
```

<sup>1</sup> uses `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV()` and does not use `joblib()`

<sup>2</sup> uses `dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV()` to replace `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV()` and uses `joblib()`

**Notes about code and output in this answer**

- I noticed in your question, you had the order of `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV()` and `cross_val_score` inverted, compared to the example in the docs

  - not sure if this effects your question too much, but thought I would mention it
- I do not have experience with nested cross validation so I cannot comment on whether `Client(..., n_workers=n, threads_per_worker=m)`, with `n>1` and/or `m=4 or m=8`, is acceptable/incorrect

**General comments about usage of `dask_ml`** (as I understand it)

- [Case 1](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.wrappers.ParallelPostFit.html#dask_ml.wrappers.ParallelPostFit): if the training data is small enough to fit into memory on a single machine, **but** the testing dataset does not fit into memory, you can use the wrapper [`ParallelPostFit`](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.wrappers.ParallelPostFit.html#dask_ml.wrappers.ParallelPostFit)

  - read testing data in parallel onto a cluster
  - make predictions on testing data in parallel, using all workers on the cluster
  - IIUC, this case is not relevant to your question
- [Case 2](https://ml.dask.org/joblib.html#joblib): if you want to use `joblib` to train a large `scikit-learn` model on a cluster (but training/testing data fits in memory) - a.k.a. distributed `scikit-learn` - then you could use a cluster to do the training and the skeleton code (per the `dask_ml` docs) is shown below

  - IIUC this case is

    - relevant to your question
    - the approach that I have used in this answer

System Details (used for executing code)

```
dask==1.2.0
dask-ml==0.12.0
numpy==1.16.2+mkl
pandas==0.24.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
sklearn==0.0
OS==Windows 8 (64-bit)
Python version (import platform; print(platform.python_version()))==3.7.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response. Unfortunately trying to copy in the joblib code as you have seems to have my models running forever with no output. However, using the dask gridsearch alone does indeed work, although for all models except keras, but this is still a great improvement for me.

Comment: @DN1, Glad it was somewhat helpful. Strange that you were having trouble with `joblib` - the implementation I showed was directly per the appropriate case (my Case 2) for your problem in the `dask_ml` [docs](https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/stable/joblib.html#joblib). The only thing I can think of is try it on a different machine or with a smaller dataset/simplest model, just to see if it even completes or if it offers other clues about the slow execution.