# How to get nested cross validation to run on multiple cores?

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, nested

Following up from my question yesterday ([How to speed up nested cross validation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808504/how-to-speed-up-nested-cross-validation-in-python)) I am trying to run models in parallel processing, however with my code is it possible to check if these models, each requiring 1 core only to run on, could run on cores in parallel or whether with this code it will always be 1 core only taking on the models 1 at a time?

I have access to higher powered computing where I could ask for 6 cores, a core per model, however, I am not sure with my code whether the models would actually be assigned their own core and run in parallel. If that makes sense (apologies if this is completely misinformed, as I am trying to learn as I go, any help would be appreciated). With n_jobs=1 for each of my models in their gridsearch can I further specifiy for each to have their own core?

Here is my code:

```
dataset= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = dataset.drop(["gene"],1)
df = data.iloc[:,0:24]
df = df.fillna(0)
X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_value = le.fit_transform(["certain", "likely", "possible", "unlikely"])
Y = le.fit_transform(data["category"])

sm = SMOTE(random_state=100)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)

seed = 7
logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear',multi_class='auto')
LR_par= {'penalty':['l1'], 'C': [0.5, 1, 5, 10], 'max_iter':[500, 1000, 5000]}

rfc =RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {'bootstrap': [True, False],
              'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
              'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4,25],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 25],
              'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]}

mlp = MLPClassifier(random_state=seed)
parameter_space = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,20), (10,20,10), (50,)],
     'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
     'solver': ['adam', 'sgd'],
     'max_iter': [10000],
     'alpha': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001],
     'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}

gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(min_samples_split=25, min_samples_leaf=25)
param = {"loss":["deviance"],
    "learning_rate": [0.15,0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001],
    "min_samples_split": [2, 5, 10, 25],
    "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 4,25],
    "max_depth":[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
    "max_features":['auto', 'sqrt'],
    "criterion": ["friedman_mse"],
    "n_estimators":[200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]
    }

svm = SVC(gamma="scale", probability=True)
tuned_parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':(1,0.25,0.5,0.75)}

def baseline_model(optimizer='adam', learn_rate=0.01):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X_res.shape[1], activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu')) #8 is the dim/ the number of hidden units (units are the kernel)
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

keras = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, batch_size=32, epochs=100, verbose=0)
learn_rate = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
kerasparams = dict(optimizer=optimizer, learn_rate=learn_rate)

inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

models = []
models.append(('GBM', GridSearchCV(gbm, param, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('RFC', GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('LR', GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('SVM', GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('MLP', GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))
models.append(('Keras', GridSearchCV(estimator=keras, param_grid=kerasparams, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=1)))

results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


for name, model in models:
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
    print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_))
```

Edit: I have now tried my for loop as:

```
def run_models(models):
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    print(msg)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Test set accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test, Y_test)*100),  '%')
    #print("Best Estimator: \n{}\n".format(model.best_estimator_))
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(model.best_params_))
    print("Best CV Score: \n{}\n".format(model.best_score_))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    pool.map(run_models, models)
```

However this seems to run indefinitely with no errors but no output

Edit: on trying to changing multiprocessing to not be IDLE I have tried:

```
def run_models(models):
    nested_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_res, y_res, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(nested_cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Nested CV Accuracy %s: %f (+/- %f )" % (name, nested_cv_results.mean()*100, nested_cv_results.std()*100)
    return msg, model.best_params_

for name, model in models:    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool()                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
        pool.map(run_models, model)
```

However this gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'GridSearchCV' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190668/multiprocessing-a-for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks ideal for my problem, I will try to apply this and see how it goes.

Comment: I have tried applying this now, but it seems to not give me any output, although I understand it may just need more time, is there a way to confirm it is applying the multiprocessing correctly?

Comment: How are you running it?  I know it behaves strangely in IDLE.  You also may be better off returning the values from the function and doing the printing in the main loop

Comment: Thank you for this response, I have had a go at doing as you suggest and put this work in my question now (although apologies as I am a beginner so likely this is not very good) let me know if you have any further advice.